# Using AugmentedImages with correct position/rotation after hosting a CloudAnchor

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm developing an AR app with arcore for multiple users. Therefore, I'm using a cloud anchor (like in the cloud anchor example) and want to add some augmented images. Before I host the cloud anchor the virtual objects will be shown on top of the augmented images and everything is fine. After the cloud anchor is set (and hosted) the virtual objects of the augmented image are shown at a totally different position. Their position and rotation transforms when moving the augmented image but in an unexpected way. It probably has something to do with the ARCoreWorldOriginHelper-class which translates the unity-positions into the cloud anchor-related positions but I don't know how to fix this.

I have already tried different setups. When adding an AugmentedImageVisualizer (like in the AugmentedImage example) I use the ARCoreWorldOriginHelper to translate the anchor of the image.

```cs
        //Image augmentation. Get updated images for this frame.
        Session.GetTrackables<AugmentedImage>(augmentedImages, TrackableQueryFilter.Updated);

        //Create visualizers for updated augmented images that are tracking and do not previously have a visualizer. Remove visualizers for stopped images.
        foreach(AugmentedImage image in augmentedImages)
        {
            ARImageVisualizer visualizer = null;

            //when visualizer was added before
            visualizers.TryGetValue(image.DatabaseIndex, out visualizer);

            Debug.Log("Tracking State is " + image.TrackingState);

            //if no visualizer was found, add one
            if(visualizer == null && image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracking)
            {
                //Anchor anchor = image.CreateAnchor(image.CenterPose);
                Anchor anchor = image.CreateAnchor(ARCoreWorldOriginHelper.WorldToAnchorPose(image.CenterPose));
                visualizer = (ARImageVisualizer)Instantiate(ARImageVisualizer, anchor.transform);
                visualizer.Image = image;
                visualizers.Add(image.DatabaseIndex, visualizer);
            }
            //if tracking has stopped and will never resume
            else if ((visualizer != null && image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Stopped))
            {
                visualizers.Remove(image.DatabaseIndex);
                Destroy(visualizer.transform.parent.gameObject);    //destroy visualizer
            }
        }
```

In the AugmentedImageVisualizer I tried the normal procedure: only changing the localPosition. I also tried to translate this with the ARCoreWorldOriginHelper (only with FrameUpperRight) but this didn't work at all (sometimes I couldn't even find the virtual objects).

```cs
//if no image is tracked, disable visualized object
        if (Image == null || Image.TrackingState != TrackingState.Tracking || Image.TrackingMethod != AugmentedImageTrackingMethod.FullTracking)
        {
            FrameLowerLeft.SetActive(false);
            FrameLowerRight.SetActive(false);
            FrameUpperLeft.SetActive(false);
            FrameUpperRight.SetActive(false);
            return;
        }

        float halfWidth = Image.ExtentX / 2;
        float halfHeight = Image.ExtentZ / 2;
        FrameLowerLeft.transform.localPosition = (halfWidth * Vector3.left) + (halfHeight * Vector3.back);
        FrameLowerRight.transform.localPosition = (halfWidth * Vector3.right) + (halfHeight * Vector3.back);
        FrameUpperLeft.transform.localPosition = (halfWidth * Vector3.left) + (halfHeight * Vector3.forward);
        //FrameUpperRight.transform.localPosition = (halfWidth * Vector3.right) + (halfHeight * Vector3.forward);

                Pose framePose = ARCoreWorldOriginHelper.WorldToAnchorPose(new Pose((halfWidth * Vector3.right) + (halfHeight * Vector3.forward), FrameUpperRight.transform.localRotation));
                FrameUpperRight.transform.localPosition = framePose.position;

        FrameLowerLeft.SetActive(true);
        FrameLowerRight.SetActive(true);
        FrameUpperLeft.SetActive(true);
        FrameUpperRight.SetActive(true);
```

Does anybody already tried this and know what to change?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found out what to do. The problem is, that you can't move the anchor to a different position. The anchor will always be on the image. Even as a child of some other gameobject it is impossible to move the anchor. So to achieve an offset for the augmented images when the smartphone/ARCoreRoot is not the world anchor anymore but the cloud anchor is, you don#t need to create an anchor. You just instantiate the visualizer and make it a child of another gameobject which gets the offset. Then you update the real position of the visualizer in every frame. With the offset it will be shown correctly on the image. In the visualizer itself you can use the normal code:

```cs
     //Image augmentation. Get updated images for this frame.
        Session.GetTrackables<AugmentedImage>(augmentedImages, TrackableQueryFilter.Updated);

        //Create visualizers for updated augmented images that are tracking and do not previously have a visualizer. Remove visualizers for stopped images.
        foreach(AugmentedImage image in augmentedImages)
        {
            ARImageVisualizer visualizer = null;

            //when visualizer was added before
            visualizers.TryGetValue(image.DatabaseIndex, out visualizer);

            //if no visualizer was found, add one
            if(visualizer == null && image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracking)
            {
                //AugmentedImages is the parent gameobject with the offset
                visualizer = (ARImageVisualizer)Instantiate(ARImageVisualizer, image.CenterPose.position, image.CenterPose.rotation, AugmentedImages.transform);
                visualizer.Image = image;
                visualizers.Add(image.DatabaseIndex, visualizer);
            }
            //if tracking has stopped and will never resume
            else if ((visualizer != null && image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Stopped))
            {
                visualizers.Remove(image.DatabaseIndex);
                Destroy(visualizer.transform.parent.gameObject);    //destroy visualizer
            }
            visualizer.transform.localPosition = image.CenterPose.position;
            visualizer.transform.localRotation = image.CenterPose.rotation;
        }
```

```cs
//if no image is tracked, disable visualized object
        if (Image == null || Image.TrackingState != TrackingState.Tracking || Image.TrackingMethod != AugmentedImageTrackingMethod.FullTracking)
        {
            FrameLowerLeft.SetActive(false);
            FrameLowerRight.SetActive(false);
            FrameUpperLeft.SetActive(false);
            FrameUpperRight.SetActive(false);
            return;
        }

        float halfWidth = Image.ExtentX / 2;
        float halfHeight = Image.ExtentZ / 2;
        FrameLowerLeft.transform.localPosition = (halfWidth * Vector3.left) + (halfHeight * Vector3.back);
        FrameLowerRight.transform.localPosition = (halfWidth * Vector3.right) + (halfHeight * Vector3.back);
        FrameUpperLeft.transform.localPosition = (halfWidth * Vector3.left) + (halfHeight * Vector3.forward);
        FrameUpperRight.transform.localPosition = (halfWidth * Vector3.right) + (halfHeight * Vector3.forward);


        FrameLowerLeft.SetActive(true);
        FrameLowerRight.SetActive(true);
        FrameUpperLeft.SetActive(true);
        FrameUpperRight.SetActive(true);
```